# Laravel - How to Only Display <a> when a field is NULL

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 project, I have a field called manager_employee_goal_comment. The default is NULL

I want to only display the  when the field is NULL. I applied this, but it didn't work:

```
   @if ($goal->manager_employee_goal_comment == NULL)
            <a class="btn btn-xs btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#comment{{ $goal->id }}"   data-original-title="Comment">Comment</a>
   @endif
```

What do I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: You say *"when the field is NULL"*, but you're using `!= NULL`, which is "*when the field is NOT NULL*"... Do you maybe mean `== NULL`?

Comment: @TimLewis - Yes. Sorry, I mean == NULL

Comment: So change your code to reflect what you actually want... Or am I missing something?

Comment: I am also a bit confused. Is your problem resolved @mikefolu ?

Comment: @apokryfos - No. Not resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience, Blade provides an `@unless` directive

> The command @unless checks if our expression returns FALSE – then
>   shows the following data. If the expression returns TRUE – it will
>   ignore the inner part.

```
@unless($goal->manager_employee_goal_comment)
    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#comment{{ $goal->id }}"   data-original-title="Comment">Comment</a>
@endunless
```

Beautiful and self expressive! Nah ?

Comment: Problem not resolved. Or could it be because the field is longtext

Comment: what do you get if you dd($goal->manager_employee_goal_comment); ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use PHP [`is_null`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) or [`empty`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) functions:

```php
@if (is_null($goal->manager_employee_goal_comment))
    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#comment{{ $goal->id }}"   data-original-title="Comment">Comment</a>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any php helper, just put the *"!"* to negate, in that case it will check if it is null.

```
@if (!$goal->manager_employee_goal_comment)
    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#comment{{ $goal->id }}"   data-original-title="Comment">Comment</a>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.

```
@if (empty($goal->manager_employee_goal_comment))
    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#comment{{ $goal->id }}"   data-original-title="Comment">Comment</a>
@endif
```